How to partial specialise a non-argument template, but also have variable templates for arguments
I have a manager class, allows the user to create components via a public interface. The use can specify the component type, and pass in the construction arguments to the manager class, which will create the component object.
However, I am trying to restrict the user from creating certain component type, so their specialisations are private. But because the component type is not a function argument, I can't figure out how to specialise it.
I am getting the error

template-id 'add_component' in declaration of primary template

#include <utility>

struct A {
    A(float x) {}
};

struct B {
    B(int x) {}
};

class Manager {
public:
    // Allow users to add components via a public interface.
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    T* add_component(Args&&... _args) {
        return new T(std::forward<Args>(_args)...);
    }

private:
    // But there are certain components that should only be added by the manager.
    template<typename... Args>
    B* add_component<B>(Args&&... _args) {
        return new B(std::forward<Args>(_args)...);
    }
};

int main() {
    Manager m;
    m.add_component<A>(5.0f); // OK
    m.add_component<B>(42); // Not OK
    return 0;
}


Also ...Args is invalid.

I have added an MRE. I am perfectly familiar with C++, and just need help with a specific template case. Usually, I know we will leave out the typename inside the <> in the specialisation. But in this case, I still need ...Args, which is why I left it in. This is not the only combination I tried.

Your stated goal is "restrict the user from creating certain component type" but your question (from the title, implied by the question body) is "How to partial specialise".  That is your question is about your attempted solution rather than the root question. Compare to XY problem. Maybe you should refocus your question on your real goal instead of asking how to do something (partially specialize a function template) that the language does not allow?

@TypeDefinition Now you just need to change <B> to <B, Args...>. But that won't work either here because function templates can't be partially specialized.

Why not just use constexpr if ? as function templates can't be partially specialized.

The simplest option would be to just use constexpr if as shown below:
class Manager {
public:
    
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    T* add_component(Args&&... _args) {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, B>){
            return new B(std::forward<Args>(_args)...);
              
        }
        else 
        {
           return new T(std::forward<Args>(_args)...);
        }
        
    }

private:
    
};

Working demo

The point is that I want the specialised version to be private, while the generic version be public. Reason being that I have many component types. Some of them should be allowed to be added by the user. But some should only be added by the manager. So their add_component() function is private so only the manager can call them.

Basically I'm hoping to "lock down" specific specialisations of the function.

Okay I don't think what I am trying to achieve is possible via template specialisation. But since your solution answers the title, I will mark it as the solution. Thank you.
